# How to connect AWS S3 credentials in a modular shiny app

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, shiny, shinydashboard

Running a shiny app with multiple folders served on shinyapps.io. The app has a function which pulls data from S3 (using a wrapper around `get_bucket()`), which works fine locally as I set the AWS secret and credentials in my project .Renviron file, but once pushed I get a HTTP 403 error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Forbidden (HTTP 403).
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Things I have tried:

- including the aws key, secret, and region directly in the `get_bucket()` call
- changing bucket setting in aws to "open access"
- setting the credentials in global.R file which includes `sys.setenv()`
- adding a .Renviron to the main project folder with the credentials
- Adding the credentials in the server.R file (to test, for confidentiality I don't want to do this)

I'm completely out of ideas on this one. It stems into a broader question of how to set .Renviron variables in a shinyapps.io app. Things I've read say to add to the main folder or other options, but as I say above hasn't worked.

I am reading the data in with `shiny::reactivePoll()` but don't see how this is the issue.

Thanks for your help, been stuck on this for days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, all along, the answer was in directly calling `Sys.getenv()` in the `get_bucket()`

```
get_bucket(s3BucketName,
                       "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = Sys.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
                       "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = Sys.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
```

Which could call on the .Renviron I had in the main directory. I think in my previous attempts I had either a) not called on it correctly with `Sys.getenv()` or forget to address it properly.