# Deploy R application in AWS SageMaker RStudio

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, rstudio, amazon-sagemaker

I have an analytics application written in R, using the Shiny package.I build the code using RStudio IDE in AWS SageMaker. Could you please guide the possible ways that I can deploy the web app in AWS and make it available in the public internet. We don't like to use ec2.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891608/how-to-connect-aws-s3-credentials-in-a-modular-shiny-app

Comment: I am looking for an option to deploy in AWS.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you will need RStudio Connect. Once you have a server up and running, you can connect your RStudio on SageMaker installation to that server and deploy seamlessly.

I know you say you don't like EC2, but your best bet at the moment is to follow the instructions of this blog [Host RStudio Connect and Package Manager for ML development in RStudio on Amazon SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/host-rstudio-connect-and-package-manager-for-ml-development-in-rstudio-on-amazon-sagemaker/) on how to achieve this. It also includes CDK code, so you can kickstart and not even touch EC2 (just follow the instructions, assuming you are broadly familiar with [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/index.html)).

Comment: Same solution I use

Comment: @Isaiah  Thank you both for sharing the details. I am quite new to sagemaker and R, the AWS document is overwhelming. If possible could you please share a document which would help to setup infrastructure without using CDK. In Sagemaker Rstudio the domain has been created and from AWS marketplace Rstudio connect has been procured, now i like to know how can i keep my application running all the time for external users.